# VS 2012 EF Designer View not updating Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I am having a weird issue that seemed to come out of nowhere with Entity Framework v5 in Visual Studio 2012.

Today, I went to updated my model from my DB, because I added a new row column to a table. After updating it I saw the new column in the view, but when trying to reference it in the code I got errors. Turns out, the view was updated, but the Designer.cs class was not (I recreated the model). I tried this two more times and could not get the designer class to update.

I assumed it was an issue with the .edml file so I deleted it and recreated it. Now I am noticing that any changes I make in the view will not be reflected in the designer. I can change the namespace, tables, ect. and they will change in the view and the view only. I already re-added my references, but no luck. I am also getting connection issues now (which I am assuming are related to nothing but the view updating).

Has anyone else encountered this issue? I could always just go and edit the code on my own, but it is time consuming and less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the model (Ctrl+S or the Save button in Visual Studio) to regenerate the *.Designer.cs file (and other model files) after the model is changed.